# Creating an exploding/sanding effect in OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I'm currently working on a program that renders a model and creates an exploding and sanding effect like the exact one described in this article: https://jiadongchen.com/2020/07/using-the-geometry-shader-to-implement-model-explosion-effect/

I'm identified the steps as:

1. Reduce the 3 points of the triangle into a single point
2. Move points according to physics equation

I'm stuck on part 1. Here is what I have so far in my geometry shader file:

```
#version 330 core
// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;


in VS_OUT {
    vec2 UV;
} gs_in[];


out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform float current_time;
uniform int boom;

vec3 GetNormal()
{
    vec3 a = vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[1].gl_Position);
    vec3 b = vec3(gl_in[2].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[1].gl_Position);
    return normalize(cross(a, b));
}

vec4 explode(vec4 position, vec3 normal, int boom)
{
    vec3 direction;
    float vb;
    float magnitude = 1.0;
    if (boom ==1){
        vb=(abs(sin(current_time/3.0))/ 2.0) * magnitude;
        direction = normal * vb; 
    }
    else {
        direction = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    }
    return position + vec4(direction, 0.0);
}

void main() {    
    vec3 normal = GetNormal();

    if (boom == 1) {
    gl_Position = (gl_in[0].gl_Position + gl_in[1].gl_Position + gl_in[2].gl_Position) / 3.0;
        TexCoords = gs_in[0].UV;
        EmitVertex();
    } else {
    gl_Position = explode(gl_in[0].gl_Position, normal,boom);
        TexCoords = gs_in[0].UV;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = explode(gl_in[1].gl_Position, normal,boom);
        TexCoords = gs_in[1].UV;
        EmitVertex();
        gl_Position = explode(gl_in[2].gl_Position, normal,boom);
        TexCoords = gs_in[2].UV;
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

When boom = 1 (user sets this), I want the triangle vertices to turn into a single point. However, nothing shows up when this happens. The triangles show up fine though.

However when I change this line `layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;` to `layout (points, max_vertices=1) out;`, it renders the model as singular points. However, I need it to render first as the entire model and then explode when the user specifies. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is too broad, you should focus it more. What is the output you are currently having for example with your existing code? Have you done some debugging to understand which parts are doing what?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.